# go.mod replace directive is ignored

Tags: go, module

I'm using the Go thrift package from Apache, which is at `lib/go/thrift` in the Git repo at `git.apache.org/thrift.git`.  This is the import statement:

```
import "git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift"
```

This works fine for using the official Apache code but we needed to make a change to the Apache code so I just added a replace directive to the `go.mod` file for the project to pick up our changed version of the package:

```
replace git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift => <local_path>/lib/go/thrift
```

where `<local_path>` is where the (patched) git repo was saved.  I added a `go.mod` file to this location (`<local_path>/lib/go/thrift`) simply containing this:

```
module git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift

go 1.12
```

However the Go compiler (`$ go build`) insists on downloading and using the Apache package and is ignoring the `replace` directive.  Any ideas on the cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/ ? Seems like the replace directive must come before the require directive. Can you post a sanitized version of your go.mod?

Comment: @T0xicCode "Seems like the replace directive must come before the require directive." No.

Comment: @T0xicCode I moved the replace before require and it made no difference.  I have included a (sanitized) version of go.mod above.

Answer (score 3):

The fix I found (after much experimenting) is to remove the `go.mod` file from `<local_path>/lib/go/thrift` (this step was **essential**) and add this `go.mod` file to `<local_path>`:

```
module git.apache.org/thrift.git

go 1.12
```

Plus also change the `replace` directive to remove the `lib/go/thrift` part like this:

```
replace git.apache.org/thrift.git => <local_path>
```

The import statement was unchanged.